# Cannot inline pictures using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and I am trying to have on the same line 4 pictures. 
I can do it with 3 but cannot do it with 4.

The fullwidth is 100% and so the blocks should be 25% each with no padding and no margin.

The section is just below the our latest post: http://0ede3ba2fd.testurl.ws/Wordpress03/blog-3/

How can I find where my error is?

Comment: Questions here must be self-contained, i.e. they must have a [mcve]. External links are subject to amendment and deletion, so we tend to say that questions that rely on them are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```html
.ds-grid-blog .et_pb_ajax_pagination_container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
}


.ds-grid-blog .pagination {
        clear: both;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your first item [.column size-1of3] has 2 article.
please check your html.
if you want to show 4 items
[.column size-1of3] should be has 1 article and change your class from [.column size-1of3] to [.column size-1of4]

Answer (score 0):

you can make css like below code.

```
<style>
.et_pb_column_4_4{
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
```